# What is IsDynamicGitRepository flag in GitVersion tool

Tags: gitversion

When I run **gitversion init** in a git working directory, I am shown, among others, the following.

`IsDynamicGitRepository: False`

I am new to gitversion tool, so please help me understand what dynamic repository mean here.

[image: What is Dynamic Git Repository in GitVersion tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic Repositories are explained in GitVersion's documentation](https://gitversion.net/docs/more-info/dynamic-repositories) and simply put, a repository is considered dynamic if `/url [the url of your git repo]` is used instead of the local `.git` folder when running GitVersion on the command line.